# how to combine sentences in several straight column cells based on dates in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Consider the picture below. I have a list of transactions, and details of each transaction span several rows (see third column). Date is populated only on the first row of transaction, so if Date is empty, it means that this row belongs to the same transaction. What I'm trying to achieve is to concatenate all transaction details for each transaction and store them in one cell, like shown in the Alias column for the first two transactions.
[image]

Comment: Please explain what exactly you are trying to achieve and give an example of expected output. Also consider asking this question on SuperUser if it's not related to VBA or to complex formula development.

Comment: my expected output like in column ALIAS, Thanks

Comment: Unclear question, missing your own attempt. Please have a look at [ask] a question with a [mcve] and edit your question accordingly =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your table so that the top left cell is in cell A1, and in your Alias column paste the following formula:
`=IF(A2 <>"",TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(C2))&":"&ADDRESS(IFNA(ROW()+MATCH("*",A3:$A$1048576,0)-1, 1048576), COLUMN(C2)))), "")`
Here's what it does:

- `IF` part makes sure text is only displayed where Date is not empty
- `TEXTJOIN` concatenates text in cells returned by `INDIRECT` formula and separates them with a space
- `INDIRECT` converts text returned by two `ADDRESS` formulas into a cell reference, that can be used in other formulas
- First `ADDRESS` returns cell in column "Transaction Detail" on current row. Second `ADDRESS` uses `MATCH` to find the beginning of next transaction (next non-empty Date), and returns address of a cell above it. If this is the last transaction, it returns the last cell on the sheet (row 1048576).

### **EDIT:**

Since you are using Excel 2013, which has neither `TEXTJOIN` nor `CONCAT`, and `CONCATENATE` cannot work with ranges, you'll need to use a user-defined function. To do this:

- Save your workbook in .xlsm format (macro enabled workbook)
- Press Alt+F11 to open VBA Editor.
- Go to Insert/Module...
- Open the module and insert this code for a custom textjoin function:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function MyTextJoin(ByVal Delimiter As String, ByVal IgnoreEmpty As Boolean, ParamArray Texts() As Variant) As String
    Dim Result As String
    Dim CurrentText As Integer
    Dim CurrentCell As Range
    For CurrentText = LBound(Texts) To UBound(Texts)
        If TypeOf Texts(CurrentText) Is Range Then
            For Each CurrentCell In Texts(CurrentText)
                If CurrentCell.Value <> "" Or Not IgnoreEmpty Then
                    Result = Result & CurrentCell.Value & Delimiter
                End If
            Next CurrentCell
        Else
            If Texts(CurrentText) <> "" Or Not IgnoreEmpty Then
                Result = Result & CStr(Texts(CurrentText)) & Delimiter
            End If
        End If
    Next CurrentText

    If Right$(Result, Len(Delimiter)) = Delimiter Then
        Result = Left$(Result, Len(Result) - Len(Delimiter))
    End If

    MyTextJoin = Result

End Function
```

- Change your formula to `=IF(A2 <>"",mytextjoin(" ", TRUE, INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(C2))&":"&ADDRESS(IFNA(ROW()+MATCH("*",A3:$A$1048576,0)-1, 1048576), COLUMN(C2)))), "")`

This solution will work much slower than using built-in function, but it should solve your issue.

Comment: @Rachmad, my apologies, I've been using this formula on 4 rows of test data and forgot to change a cell reference. Please try the corrected formula. I've edited the answer

Comment: sory sir, I have tried but It didnt work

Comment: @Rachmad, what did it show in the Alias column? Also, did you try the edited version? I made a few mistakes there, now it should be working.

Comment: it show #NAME, yes I have edited several

Comment: What is your Excel version and what reference style are you using (R1C1 or A1)?

Comment: Also, what is the language of Excel? You might have to translate the formulas to your language if it's not in English

Comment: my excel style A1 and my language in english

Comment: in my excel there is no TEXTJOIN

Comment: my excel 2013 version, I have tried again and the result not combine. using CONCATENATE.

Comment: @Rachmad, I've posted an edit which should solve it for your version of Excel. Please let me know if it works

Comment: awesome, this solved my problem. Thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **CONCATENATE** function as explained in attached screenshot [Excel using CONCATENATE function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLDob.png)

Comment: it can't automatically, cz the column transaction detail have different size, example 2 cell ,3 cell etc